# What does it mean when the second derivative at a point is infinite?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What does it mean when the second derivative of a function at a certain point is infinite?

What would be neat examples that illustrate what happens?

When the first derivative is infinite you get a vertical slope. Does something similar happen with an infinite second derivative?

In other words: can you see in $f(x)$ that $f''(x_{inf})\to\infty$?

Comment: $x \mapsto x^{\frac 43}$ at $0$. Roughly, this means the "speed" at which the tangents to the graph change slope about $x=0$ gets arbitrarily large as $x \to 0$.

Comment: Well, get any function with a point where the value approaches infinity, then integrate it twice, you'll have a function where the second derivative at the original point in infinite

Comment: @ArianaGrande Is it possible to see in $f(x)$ that $f''(x_{inf})\to\infty$?

Comment: @ImreVégh If it already have a point approaching  infinity, then it's double derivative is infinity, if there is no points approaching infinity, the derivatives of it would not approach infinity. Note than it has to approach infinity from both sides

Comment: @ArianaGrande: What do you mean by "a point where the value approaches infinity"? The value at a fixed point doesn't approach *anything*.

Comment: @CameronBuie lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)=\infty

Comment: @ArianaGrande use dollar signs to enclose formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the comments above mentioned *curvature* so it may be helpful to point out that second derivative can be interpreted geometrically as the curvature of the graph.  Thus the graph of the $C^1$ function $y=x^{3/2}$ looks roughly like a parabola but as you get closer and closer to the origin the radius of the osculating circle at a point on the graph will tend to zero.   In this sense one can think of "infinite second derivative" at the origin in terms of the curvature "exploding" while the osculating circle shrinks to a point. (Note that the curvature is the reciprocal of the radius of the osculating circle.)

Comment: It might have been more illustrative to say that if your curvature is "exploding" then the radius of curvature goes to zero; that is, your osculating circle shrinks to a point.

Answer (score 1):

When the first derivative has a jump, the second derivative is infinite.  So a sharp angle in the graph will cause an infinite second derivative.

Comment: The graph of $f(x)=x^{\frac{4}{3}}$ does not have a sharp angle in the graph at $x=0$ while $f''(0)\to\infty$ or does it?

Comment: No, you are right, it is not sharp  when the first derivative doesn't have a jump.